# Why ReentrantLock algorithm from book is not working?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Today I read [Nir Shavit, Maurice Herlihy, *The Art of Multiprocessor Programming*](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/the-art-of/9780123705914/) and came across one very incomprehensible (**for me personally**) thing.

So, i found implementation of *ReentrantLock* in java (*for me it's page 188, chapter 8*):

```
class SimpleReentrantLock implements Lock {

    Lock lock;
    Condition condition;
    long owner, holdCount;

    SimpleReentrantLock() {
        lock = new SimpleLock();
        condition = lock.newCondition();
        owner = 0;
        holdCount = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void lock() {
        long me = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        lock.lock();
        if (owner == me) {
            holdCount++;
            return;
        }

        while (holdCount != 0) {
            try {
                condition.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        owner = me;
        holdCount = 1L;
    }

    @Override
    public void unlock() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (holdCount == 0 || owner != Thread.currentThread().getId()) {
                throw new IllegalMonitorStateException();
            }

            holdCount--;
            if (holdCount == 0) {
                condition.signal();
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    // Other methods for Lock interface...
}
```

I analyzed this code and still not fully understand it.

So, i can use `ReentrantLock` from `java.util.concurrent.locks` in such way:

```
lock.lock();
lock.lock();
// Some code here...
lock.unlock();
lock.unlock();
```

And it will be OK, because it's ReentrantLock, i can acquire critical section multiple times.

For example, you can find spin-lock implementation from this book:

```
class TASLock implements Lock {
    private AtomicBoolean state = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    @Override
    public void lock() {
        while(state.getAndSet(true));
    }

    @Override
    public void unlock() {
        state.set(false);
    }

    // Other Lock methods...
}
```

This implementation is working as expected.

So, you can notice from `SimpleReentrantLock` next thing:

```
 lock = new SimpleLock();
```

As author tell us:

> we initialize the internal lock field to an object of a (fictitious) SimpleLock class which is is presumably not reentrant

But actually, i have implementation of non-reentrant lock (`TASLock`), so i will do next inlining:

```
lock = new TTASLock();
```

And finally, when i will try to execute next code, i will get deadlock:

```
new Thread(() -> {
            lock.lock();
            lock.lock();
            System.out.println("No deadlock found.");
            lock.unlock();
            lock.unlock();
}).start();
```

And it looks pretty clear, because in `lock` method we have such code:

```
 lock.lock();
```

We actually trying to acquire the critical section twice on the same lock object without any preconditions.

Is the wrong algorithm indicated in the book? Or didn’t I understand something?

Comment: Now what is your question?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala my question: Is the wrong algorithm indicated in the book? Or didn’t I understand something?

Comment: Because inside this book such algorithm of mutex is called "reentrant", which actually not, as i see. So, i little bit confused and that's why i'am asking this question.

Comment: Why do you say that it is not reentrant or not working? What is the proof you have?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala reentrant lock don't have deadlocks if you will acquire it multiple times on the same mutex. So, pls, check my examples. Anyway, you can test it by yourself, because i shared code (from book).

Comment: Well, the `SimpleLock` class is missing here?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala as author said: we initialize the internal lock field to an object of a (fictitious) SimpleLock class which is is presumably not reentrant. So i replace it with another implementation of not reentrant lock (TASLock). Do you check the question? :)

Comment: Ok, I can see one mistake, that is you have to call `lock();` on `SimpleReentrantLock` but not on `TASLock` instance. The other point is your non reentrant lock, keep returning true once it is acquired. So when you call `lock()` for the second time the while loop condition becomes true and it keeps busy waiting until that condition becomes false. But for that you have to call `unlock()` which is waiting for the previous `lock()` operation to complete. And now it deadlocks. Nothing wrong with the book, but your nonreentrant lock implementation.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala no, it's not my implementation of TASLock, it's taken from book. Also, you said that i need to use another implementation of SimpleLock? Or what? Because inside SimpleReentrantLock lock's method there is just always basically invocation of another "non-reentrant" lock ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @RavindraRanwala also, i really don't understand your statement: The other point is your non reentrant lock, keep returning true once it is acquired. Why Test-and-set lock must return something?

Comment: After you setting it to true `while (state.getAndSet(true));` it keeps busy waiting in the while loop until you set it to false via unlock.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212854/discussion-between-slandshow-and-ravindra-ranwala).

Comment: Sorry I don't support people via chat since it violates the primary purpose of having this site. You may find someone else and discuss this or shoot a mail to the author and ask the question. Alternatively you can add this to the errata if one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lock.unlock() is missing in the lock()  method. The algorithm is correct, it is a simple oversight.
As stated in the Book:

> Because these two fields are manipulated atomically, we need an internal short term lock.

To answer the question in the comment, here is the corrected version of lock():

```
    public void lock() {
    long me = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    lock.lock();
    try{
    if (owner == me) {
        holdCount++;
        return;
    }

    while (holdCount != 0) {
        try {
            condition.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    owner = me;
    holdCount = 1L;
    } finally {        
        lock.unlock();  // this call is missing
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where this unlock missed inside this code?

Comment: I added this to the anwser

Comment: So, it looks like a typo in the book.